# How to create some test spring beans before others

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have production bean A and in `@TestConfiguration` bean B. Non of those beans depends on each other. But in tests I want bean B to be instantiated before bean A. that's because B prepares local testing environment for A. How can i achieve it?

i can't just annotate A with `@DependsOn` because B is available only in some tests and i don't want to bind production code with tests.

Comment: "I want bean B to be instantiated before bean A" **Why**? Adding context like this is important. Without it, it strikes me as an XY problem. Part of the magic of Spring's DI is that you don't need to worry or care about the exact order of initialization.

Comment: @Michael added explanation: B prepares local testing environment for A

Comment: What sort of preparation?

Comment: Is it really necessary to have preparation logic in the bean `B`? Why don't you use something like `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` (for JUnit) that is specifically crated for purpose of preparation.

Comment: I've had to do this where the test needs to create external resources that your Spring application beans will need to exist prior to initializing. Using BeforeClass is too late, Spring will have already tried to load your application and barf. For example, using Spring GCP pub sub, you need the GCP subscription to exist before your Spring app loads. Probably the right thing to do is use a maven plugin that runs before the test to do this, but it can be convenient to have it all self-contained in the test.

Answer (score 1):

> But in tests I want bean B to be instantiated before bean A
>
> ...
>
> and i don't want to bind production code with tests.

Something like this?

```
@Profile("test")
@Bean
public BeanB beanB() {
    return new BeanB();
}

@Profile("test")
@Bean
public BeanA beanA(BeanB beanB) {
    return new BeanA();
}

@Profile("!test")
@Bean
public BeanA beanA() {
    return new BeanA();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do what you're asking. Your best bet is to have an optional dependency in A. In production, the dependency will be missing and so will be ignored. In the tests, you will provide a bean which contains your test preparation implementation.

Yes, you are adding a little bit of additional complexity for the sake of tests which is not ideal but it's very limited.

Forgive the terrible names:

```
interface APreparer {
    void prepareA();
}

@Component
public class A {
     public A(final Optional<APreparer> preparer) {
          preparer.ifPresent(APreparer::prepareA);
     }
}
```

Comment: Anyway, class `A` has a mention of  class `B` (which exists only in test config). I guess that's not an option for topic starter.

Comment: @KenBekov I don't understand what you mean. In this example, A requires no knowledge of B.

Comment: Now it knows about `APrepare` (which is actually `B`) and about preparation process as well. I suspect that in product mode `A` shouldn't be care of preparation process at all.

Comment: `APreparer` is **not** B. B is an **implementation** of `APreparer `. Completely different. Yes, it knows about the preparation *process* - but that process is not necessarily specific to tests, necessarily `B`, or necessarily performed at all. "A shouldn't be care of preparation process at all" In an ideal world, yes. But there's no better way to do it. The best we can do is abstract away from the test-specific nature of what's going on as much as possible.

Comment: As far as I got it, the preparation process is specific for the tests. There are no beans with functionality of `B` in product mode. Otherwise it wouldn't be a question.

Comment: @KenBekov I already said that. "In production, the dependency will be missing and so will be ignored"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TestApplication (in `src/test/java`) that trivially extends your actual Spring Boot application class and have that depend on your test bean. Then tell SpringBootTest to load your TestApplication instead of the production application.

Example TestApplication:

```
@DependsOn("beanB")
@Configuration
@Import(YourApplication.class)
public class TestApplication {}
```

Example test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
public class YourApplicationTests {
...
```